# Did I Misuse the AntiForgery.Validate Helper from WebMatrix in One of My Pages?

Tags: c#, html, forms, security, webmatrix

After seeing the AntiForgery.Validate() method error (which it is supposed to do, when the form token does not validate), and visiting this site: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery(v=vs.111).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.antiforgery%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)
for more information, it appears that I may have misused this in the past.

I have used the combination of AntiForgery.GetHTML(); and AntiForgery.Validate(); on a login page, but not sure if it makes sense to put it there. Without being logged in, the user is always "" (empty string), so I guess I originally thought that using the AntiForgery class did more than it really does. And, thus, is my question:

Am I right to assume that the only security check that the above practice performs is simply to make sure (by putting AntiForgery.Validate(); in an if(IsPost) branch) that the user who submitted the form is the same user who was logged in when the page was loaded?

If so, then, Am I also right in assuming that utilizing this class in this way has no place in a login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code on codeplex, [AntiForgery](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgery.cs) uses [AntiForgeryWorker](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryWorker.cs) which uses [TokenValidator](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a19eb63170f9#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs), the `ValidateTokens` method does do some identity and username checking.  If you aren't getting an exception thrown, it might be doing some level of validation but using "" as username.

```
if (!String.Equals(fieldToken.Username, currentUsername, (useCaseSensitiveUsernameComparison) ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    throw HttpAntiForgeryException.CreateUsernameMismatchException(fieldToken.Username, currentUsername);
}
```

However, what is the use case for "forging" a login page?  If the forger know the credentials to submit, they could just login themselves.  It might not matter if AntiForgery doesn't work to its full potential here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But the real question here is: What (if any) checking does it do other than username validation, and should I include it in login pages at all? What happens is that when a page idles too long I get a YSOD. I suppose I could just make sure that the "AntiFogery.Validate();" method comes after the part of my page that checks to see if the user is logged in and asks for their credentials again, if not.